# Admob account disabled for click on own add

Tags: android, android-studio, adsense, admob

My Admob account has been disabled and the reason they gave me was that I clicked on my own add. Its been 1 week since I have uploaded my app and they have sent me this mail now. I don't remember clicking on any of my adds.

If someone uninstalls the test app from test device and installs it on the same device from play store using a different account is it a violation to click on the add ?

And I didn't click on that either I want to find the reason behind my Admobs suspension.

What I suspect is that someone might have used my device and clicked on the add.

Answer (score 0):

Admob suspends your account only when it has strong evidence of invalid clicks that happens on your ad.  I don't know what actually happened but this is for sure the ad has been clicked intentionally   by your side.

Your adsense account will be suspended for a month with a final warning and no ads will be served from your side during this period. Next time if any of this thing (Invalid clicks) happens, your account will be suspended forever.

Until and unless Admob has strong evidence,  they don't suspend account. So you  need to figure out how the ads were clicked ...